# How to adjust p-value with Bonferroni correction?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, type-i-and-ii-errors

I think this is a simple question, but for which I've found conflicting answers around.

Let's say, I measured a biomarker in a group of patients with 5 different methods and I want to perform pairwise comparisons (i.e. 10 tests in total). For Bonferroni correction, should I divide my type I error rate by 5 (methods) or 10 (tests)?

Then, if I repeat the measurements a second time with all 5 methods and would like to compare the first and second measurements in pairs (i.e. 25 tests in total). How to adjust now?
Thanks!

Comment: How many p-values do you have for which you want to control the overall type I error rate? That’s the number by which you divide $\alpha$. A word of caution: Bonferroni is highly conservative and will sap away your power to reject false null hypotheses. The documentation for p.adjust in R gives some alternative methods.

Comment: For the first comparison study, I am doing 10 tests thus I will obtain 10 p-values. Correspondingly, 25 for the second study. Since the data used in the second study are partially the same as the first one, will this mean the number by which I divide is 35?

Comment: This “partially the same” concerns me. Please elaborate.

Comment: As described in the original post, I am referring to the case where the data will be reanalyzed in a second study. We can consider the first study to be measurement 1, and the second study to be the same measurement 1 plus measurement 2. And these are for all 5 methods. In hindsight I see that this is best done with a two-way ANOVA, but I wonder how Bonferroni would be used.